# Outlook Application wont send mails every second instance

Tags: email, outlook, office365

I know I should probably ask MS about this, but I dont know if I trust their communication tools to get me a satisfying answer.

I have recently taken the task to test an application of mine.
Part of this test is to send an e-mail to it, then log in and see if I get the result I want (this is automated)

For this the process is:

1. Open Outlook -> Send Mail
2. Close Outlook
3. Open App -> Check result
4. Open Outlook -> Send Mail
5. Close Outlook

But for some reason, every second time the outlook app is opened, (including manually opening the app to check on configurations etc.) Mails will go to the outbox but will not be sent, unless I manually trigger them to.

Now, there are possible solutions like keeping the app running continously, or telling my testing-suite to press F9 after every sent mail, but I want to tackle the root cause, and fix the underlying problem.

The Outlook Version used is the latest Version of Office 365 Outlook.

Has anyone else had this experience and figured out a fix?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this problem occured on a machine I do not own, I tried avoiding certain easy troubleshooting steps. After I couldnt find an answer on my own, and I didnt get responses here that would've helped me solve this without a wooden hammer method, I asked for permission to issue a repair to the local office 365 suite.

After the repair it had redownloaded and installed the entirety of office 365.
After connecting my company MS account to outlook, the issue no longer appeared.

I guess this counts as solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that message submission is an asynchronous process, so if you close Outlook while it is still sending, the message might end up stuck in the Outbox.
You can call `Namespace.SendAndReceive` to force submission, but it is still asynchronous. You can hook into the `SyncObject.SyncEnd` event on the first (All Accounts) `SyncObject` from the `Namespace.SyncObjects` collection and quite only after that event fires.

Comment: The message will get stuck in the outbox indefinitely, until I send it by hand, or close and restart the application.
Also the Software I use to test this process works as if someone was triggering these events over a remote session.

Comment: You really need to show your code and keep in mind that touching an item with either OOM or UI after the submission has started will abort it.

Comment: There is really no code. It's just a program simulating clicks.
And even then, when I manually operate the outlook application the problem is the same. There is no code, unless you want the sourcecode for Outlook 365.

There is code within my testing suite, but, again, the problem is universal, even when operating outlook by hand.